# Best standards for declaring variable in php

Tags: php, coding-style, standards

can any one please let me know the global declaration of php variables..i have seen one among the site like..

```
for integer start with i, eg: $iItemId
for array start with a, eg: $aItemIds
for string start with s, eg: $sItemName
```

Comment: If you accepted valid answers you might get more/better responses. Have a google for 'Hungarian notation' - some people like it, some don't

Comment: @symcbean correction: some people like it, most don't :)

Comment: @Kemo correction: some perverts like it, most people don't :o

Answer (score 3):

Use the style you are comfortable with.

But also take into account the frameworks you are using. If you use mostly the Zend Framework choosing a style different to their style may lead to "visually confusing" code, since the style switches.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use such conventions, and it is rare to see this in php, it's more a VB thing I guess...

If you give good names to variable, their types will appear. For instance, the not so strict conventions I use vor variable naming :

- `$i`, `$j`, `$k`, `$l`, etc. and all single letters variables are integers used as counters
- `$messageRow` => it's a DB result instance
- `$messageCollection`  => it's results collection
- `$messageRows` => array , Using plural denotes multiple items
- `$messageTitle` => it's a string
- `$messageVisible` or `$isMessageVisible` => it's a boolean

In fact everithing now tends to be object, except array and strings, and good naming with good comment and/or visible typecast (mainly on methods arguments, or specific use) makes variables more readable code and guessing types is easier than having a whole bunch of `$oThis` and `$oThat`

Comment: -1 don't encourage such an unreadable behaviour, please. Let's leave the capmixing to barbaric languages like java.

Comment: The question was about using typing hint in variable name, not using cap or underscore to separate words in those names.

It's a matter of choice, why vote down on this ! I work with Symfony framework everyday, and it uses this convention, it's better not mixing conventions don't you think ? 

I use underscore for string identifiers, like array keys, config names, etc.

Also, it's easier to type a cap than getting the underscore key, at least on my AZERTY keyboards

Comment: How easy can you write it is irrilevant confronted to how easy can anyone *read* it. CapMixingIsJustUnreadable, face it.

Comment: its perfectly readable imho.... 
I used a lot of underscore variables when I was working on php4 procedural projects, for me both are as readable, way more than variable like $idonthaveanywordseparator. The point is the convention to use depends more on the project convention and people you work with than you own preference or supposed readability.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is called [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), nobody seems to have mentioned that yet.

In answer to your question, I would suggest using whatever style you're most comfortable with. As long as it's consistent and readable it doesn't really matter. That said, hungarian notation isn't the most readable style...

Answer (score -2):

God, no!

Avoid like hell idiotic names LikeThisOne.

Never ever use caps in a variable name, unless it's ALLCAPS.

Use underscore to separate words if you need to.

Comment: for example Zend coding standards says "use caps". in many different languages its a standard to use caps.

Comment: Agreed. `$myvar` could be `$my_var` or `global $MYGLOBAL` perhaps, or just plain old `global $my_little_global`.

I've no real issue against camelcasing, but I'd only really do it in Class names and the like

Comment: The question was about using typing hint in variable name, not using cap or underscore to separate words in those names.

Comment: That's a pretty bad advice. These "idiotic" names are used in Zend Framework, Symfony, CakePHP and many other frameworks and libraries.

Comment: the caps and small setters will always to identify when the variable declare lengthy

Comment: "use caps" or "camelized" is more of a Java thing, not php. Method / function names should always be lowercase with underscores in php, it's far much easier to read, so why not variables too ?

Comment: lol @ this epic attempt to push anti_camel_case criticism on an ObjectOrientedCrowd.